# How does missing data occur

Tags: preprocessing, missing-data

I am new to ML.
I found that one of the preprocessing steps is to handle missing data.

My query is

- Is there a way to understand nature of missing data
- I can see that the mostly missing data is dropped or replaced with mean/mode is that the right way to go about it

Comment: For your second question: yes, some people do this but it is essentially wrong except for very specific cases addressed in @Archana David's answer. This is because complete case analysis often causes bias and reduces power, while mean/median imputation can cause bias due to underestimating the variance. Please do not do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your query is a 3 part question

- **How missing data occur**: Missing data can occur when no data value is stored for a variable, or because of nonresponse, or the information is just not available
- **Understanding missingness**: forms of missingness take different types

  1. *MCAR(missing completely at random)*:     Missing data values do not relate to any other data in the dataset and there is no pattern to the actual values of the missing data themselves.
  2. *MAR(missing at random)*: Missing data do have a relationship with other variables in the dataset. However, the actual values that are missing are random.
  3. *MNAR(missing not at random)*: The pattern of missingness is related to other variables in the dataset, but in addition, the values of the missing data are not random.
- **Handling missing data**: Once you have understood what missingness is all about. Next step is to handle them, dropping missing data or replacing with mean/mode is few of the techniques.

  1. Deletion methods

     - Listwise deletion: ideal for MCAR
     - Pairwise deletion: ideal for MAR or MCAR
  2. Single imputation:

     - Mean/Median/Mode substitution
     - Regression imputation
     - LOCF(Last observation carried forward)
  3. Model-Based methods:

     - Maximum likelihood: best maximum likelihood technique is EM (Expectation-Maximization)
     - Multiple Imputation: MICE algorithm, Amelia(ideal for time series) are few packages that handle multiple imputation.

Look into these for better understanding of your missingness

- [missing data imputation](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Egelman/arm/missing.pdf)
- [handling missing data in R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/finalfit/vignettes/missing.html)

Answer (score 1):

Pick up a copy of the [Bad Data Handbook](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/bad-data-handbook/9781449324957/) (Q. Ethan McCallum, 2012).

It's got 18 case studies by different authors on their experience with dealing with pre-processing in the wild.  Missing data is not your worst case scenario.  *Bad* data can lead you down the wrong path if you don't sanity-check your results early in the process.  It's a very enlightening read on how things can go wrong and the authors' approaches to wrangling data into something usable and useful.

*... wonders if **all** data is **bad** data to start with ...*

Answer (score 0):

> *I can see that the mostly missing data is dropped or replaced with mean/mode is that the right way to go about it*

It's mostly because you might be referring to a tutorial/blog which is not focused on that.
Or, data volume is quite high as compared to missing rows. So, might have been ignored.

> *Is there a way to understand the nature of missing data*

Yes, few good reads -

- [*Feature Engineering and Selection, Max Kuhn and Kjell Johnson*](http://www.feat.engineering/handling-missing-data.html)
- [*Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models*](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Egelman/arm/missing.pdf)
- [*Scikit-Learn doc*](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html)

Comment: For understanding missing data, I would recommend Stef van Buuren's book: Flexible imputation of missing data. You can read it online on the author's website in full.